# How to improve query count execution with mySql replicate?

Tags: mysql, replication, optimization, count

For my report I have to use count queries (name 'user_activity' for example) and then group by by another column (user_type) in another table (user table).

And its really time consuming when it comes to million records data.
So I decided to use mySql Replicate to create a slave db for my reporting purpose. But I'm still struggling with these things:

1. Are you willing to duplicate a part of your db in exchange for query speed ?
2. Is there any way to add data to user_type column automatically in 'user_activity' table (slave db) when they are syncing?
3. And how to optimize database for reading purpose? (reporting data, analytics,..)

update:
this is my create sql

Table user

```
CREATE TABLE `library_th`.`user` ( 
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL , 
`username` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
`password` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL , 
`user_type` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'this user is created automatically by system or by them himself?' , 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Table user_activity:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_activity` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `action` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'what activity did user do?',
  `datetime_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
ALTER TABLE `user_activity`
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`);
```

and my count query that I'm wanna use is:

```
select count(ua.id) as `total`, u.user_type, ua.action from user_activity ua
inner join user u on ua.user_id = u.id
group by ua.action, u.user_type
```

Comment: Please show us the actual query and the `SHOW CREATE TABLEs`.  There _may_ be a simple solution.

Comment: I updated my create and my count queries

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

Add this composite index to `user_activity`:  `INDEX(user_id, action)`.  Then

```
SELECT SUM(x.ct), u.user_type, x.action
    FROM (
        SELECT user_id, action, COUNT(*) AS ct
            FROM user_activity
            GROUP BY user_id, action
         ) x
    JOIN user u  ON x.user_id = u.id
    GROUP BY x.action, u.user_type;
```

Comment: Its faster than my old query but its still slow for 2 million records. It took ~7s to execute for the very first time.

Comment: It takes time to scan through 2 million records.

Comment: Yeah, but is there anyway to speed up that scan? like accept duplicating data by putting 'user_type' in 'user_activity' table or other methods...

Answer (score 0):

In Data Warehousing, "Summary tables" are very important for performance.

A Summary table contains counts and subtotals for each day (or other time period).  "Reports", such as your query are then run using a summary table, and can run much faster than running against the 'raw' data.

For your case, build and incrementally maintain a table with, say:
day, user_type, action, count
The first 3 columns would be the `PRIMARY KEY`, the last would be the subtotal.

You would need an index on `datetime_created` to make it more efficiently to do the nightly update.

Comment: So lets me make it clear, i have to create a table which has 4 fields, and for every insert query to my user_activity table, increase the appropriate 'count' field to 1, or i can do a cron-job to count it at the end of the day?

Comment: Plan A:  `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` to insert of bump the count.  Plan B: nightly cron job to compute the day's stats.  Plan C:  (there may be other ways.)  [More discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).